# Can watir-webdriver click a css background-image or at an arbitrary position in the browser?

Tags: css, watir-webdriver

I have a "split button" from extjs much like the "Menu Button" demo on the extjs demo page at http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/kitchensink/index.html#basic-toolbar.  The button has a drop-down arrow on the right side that is a css-background image on a parent  tag.  When the right side is clicked a menu will drop down with additional selections for the button action.  I can click the button or the em but in both cases the menu will not drop down.

I've also tried sending both the button and em javascript events in different orders ( mousedown, mouseup, click, etc) still I can only trigger the main button and cannot get the drop down menu to appear.

Somehow I need to place a mouse click precisely on that background image to get the menu to appear.  Would there be a way for watir-webdriver to click at an arbitrary position in the browser?  Assuming, of course, that I could get watir-webdriver to give me the current coordinates of the button or em.  Or is there some other way to trigger the drop down?

I posted a similar inquiry on the google watir forum, but still have no solution.  Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Comment: This might be a question for the extjs folks in terms of making the control more testable.  If there was a distinct element on that right side that could be clicked (instead of the larger element 'under' the button on the left) then it could be a lot easier to work with.  That or your might have to reverse engineer the page and see if there is some bit of javascript you can execute that would be the same thing invoked by a click

Comment: I ended up having a developer write some custom javascript to click on that type of button menu.  However, it seems that besides being a pain to automate, there is a UI problem in that the menu attached to the button cannot be opened from the keyboard (the clever approach that Justin Ko suggested).

Comment: Which could be an accessibility issue.  Most standard HTML controls don't have that problem.  This is a downside to some of these fancy menus, they look good but present testability issues, and accessability issues to people with disabilities..  (wonder what it would be like to try that thing with a screen-reader?)

Answer (score 4):

Try this, works like a charm:

```
   b.em(:class, "x-btn-split x-btn-split-right").button(:class, "x-btn-center").send_keys :down
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to expand the menu and are not specifically testing the 'click' event, you can send the down key instead:

```
browser.div(:id, 'splitbutton-1022').send_keys :down
```

This worked for the sample site on Firefox. I did not try any other browsers.

Comment: browser.button( :id, 'splitbutton-1022-btnEl' ).send_keys :down

Comment: Alas this isn't working on my particular web app although it works on the demo site.